# What is the development environment to set up when learning Objective-C under Ubuntu

Tags: objective-c, linux

I am a Java developer, I am going to start to learn objective C from scrach.

I would like to ask here, if my work station is a Ubuntu 10.04 machine, what is the development environment I have to set up for objective c programming?

For example, what is the IDE to use, what other things need to set up?

Answer (score 1):

You need a Mac with Xcode installed. Check here:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/install-xcode/

**Edit:**

If you only need Objective-c, a text editor and a gcc compiler is enough:

http://gcc.gnu.org/

Comment: Read your first answer -> took a deep breath to start swearing, while reading your second answer -> +1

Comment: @ Jacky, thank you. Actually my point is that I would like to learn objective C on a Ubuntu machine, I thought something I need to install for this purpose. Seems nothing special as both text editor and gcc are there in a ubuntu.

Comment: @ das_weezul, Ha! you described exactly what I felt after I read Jacky's answer:)

Comment: das_weezul, sorry. :P But one more thing, look at the tags... "ios" and "objective-c". It mislead me...

Comment: Oh you're right, haven't seen them ... well thats smells like another soul lost to the "other" big apple ;)

Comment: Ahahahaha. We are here to guide them... :D

Answer (score 0):

When you write that you want to learn Objective-C, most people automatically think "Oh, you want to start developing applications for MacOSX or iOS" as that is the main (an probably only) platform Objective-c is in heavy use today. So:

1. If you want to write GUI applications for MacOSX or iOS, there are tons of questions on SO of which 99% come to the conclusion that you need a Mac for that
2. If you just want to program in Objective-c for the console, or target other GUI frameworks, then just take an editor of your choice and compile the code with gcc (as @Jacky Boy suggested)

There used to be an eclipse plugin called [objectiveclipse](http://code.google.com/p/objectiveclipse/) but it seems that they have shut down the project.